# store data from radio button to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this

```
<input type="radio" name="male" id="male" value="male"/>
   <label for="male">M</label>

<input type="radio" name="female" id="female" value="female"/>
   <label for="female">F</label>
```

I'm asking which could be the best way to save trough php value `male` and `female` in a mysql database.On the mysql db I create a field as `enum` with two value: `male` and `female`

Comment: There are **a ton** of [guides, tutorials, etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20save%20to%20mysql) out there on this very subject. I recommend checking some out, and coming back with any specific issues you run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing your radio box group is wrong , Because you cant't consists both the gender at the same time.
Keep same name for both the radios , it will make just one radio selectable at a time.
And it sosent matter what you save in database , just interpret when you take it out of db.But mostly people keep (male/female) only as gender in db.And enum will do,else try varchar(5).